# Spring Security -The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I got error while running this code, there is an injection cycle in the code but I cannot find it. btw, I'm new with Spring.
How can I solve this problem? And any good documentation about it ?

Here is my code;

WebSecurityConfiguration class:

package com.trendyol.app;

```
import com.trendyol.app.auth.JwtTokenFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true) //Tüm methodlarımızdan önce security devreye girer
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ///////////////////
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configurePasswordEncoder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder  ) throws Exception{
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getBCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
    ///////////////////
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getBCryptPasswordEncoder(){
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login") //bu adress hariç
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

UserDetailsService:

```
package com.trendyol.app.auth;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


@Service
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {
    private Map<String,String > users=new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        users.put("temelt", passwordEncoder.encode("123"));
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if(users.containsKey(username)){
            return new User(username,users.get(username),new ArrayList<>());
        }
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
}
```

LOGs:
Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  webSecurityConfiguration (field private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.trendyol.app.WebSecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService)
↑     ↓
|  userDetailsService (field private org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder com.trendyol.app.auth.UserDetailsService.passwordEncoder)
└─────┘

Comment: Your security configuration needs the `UserDetailsService`, which in turn needs a `PasswordEncoder` which is created by the configuration. Hence a cycle.

Comment: how can I solve it? :))

Comment: Remove the Bean creation of BCryptPasswordEncoder from WebSecurityConfiguration and put it in a separate Configuration class

Comment: By moving the creation of the password encoder to a seperate configuration class. Tip also change your `UserDetailsService` to use a `PasswordEncoder` (the interface) instead of the concrete implementation (this won't solve it but is better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried marking your `PasswordEncoder` with the `@Lazy` tag instead of the `@Autowired` tag? From the docs:

> Indicates whether a bean is to be lazily initialized.

I had a similar problem and changing to @Lazy was one way I solved the problem. In your case it would look something like:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {
    private Map<String,String > users=new HashMap<>();

    @Lazy
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
```

See more here: [Spring Lazy Annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html)